# WebView with base64 doesn't loading the images

Tags: android, webview, base64

I have a webView and I'm getting the webContent as String from a connection getting the response and change it into inserting into database and getting it in the Main2Activity
but like I said  after changing it into base64 encodeToString the pictures doesn't show it even if I didn't change it into base64 it doesn't show anything.
**for offline use**

```
 public static String getHtml(String url) throws IOException {


    // Build and set timeout values for the request.
    URLConnection connection = (new URL(url)).openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
    connection.connect();

    // Read and store the result line by line then return the entire string.
    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        html.append(line);
    }
    in.close();

    return html.toString();
}
```

this is how i get the string 
and  my string looks like in the Log

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html id="js-context" class="js-off is-not-modern id--signed-out" lang="en" data-page-path="/money/2019/dec/10/starbucks-gift-card-refused-franchise-stores"><head><!--     __        __                      _     _      _     \ \      / /__    __ _ _ __ ___  | |__ (_)_ __(_)_ __   __ _      \ \ /\ / / _ \  / _` | '__/ _ \ | '_ \| | '__| | '_ \ / _` |       \ V  V /  __/ | (_| | | |  __/ | | | | | |  | | | | | (_| |        \_/\_/ \___|  \__,_|_|  \___| |_| |_|_|_|  |_|_| |_|\__, |                                                            |___/    Ever thought about joining us?    https://workforus.theguardian.com/careers/digital-development/     ---><title>The Starbucks gift card I bought is useless | Money | The Guardian</title><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="description" content="It won’t accept it at the Leicester University franchise and the nearest alternative is an hour away"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/><meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1"><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://assets.guim.co.uk/"/><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://i.guim.co.uk"/><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://api.nextgen.guardianapps.co.uk"/><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://hits-secure.theguardian.com"/><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//j.ophan.co.uk"/><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ophan.theguardian.com"/><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//phar.gu-web.net"/><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//www.google-analytics.com"/><link rel="preconnect" href="https://assets.guim.co.uk/"/><link rel="preconnect" href="https://i.guim.co.uk"/><link rel="preconnect" href="//interactive.guim.co.uk"/><link rel="preconnect" href="//www.google-analytics.com"/><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//sb.scorecardresearch.com"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://assets.guim.co.uk/images/favicons/fee5e2d638d1c35f6d501fa397e53329/152x152.png"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://assets.guim.co.uk/images/favicons/1fe70b29879674433702d5266abcb0d4/144x144.png"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://assets.guim.co.uk/images/favicons/c58143bd2a5b5426b6256cd90ba6eb47/120x120.png"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://assets.guim.co.uk/images/favicons/68cbd5cf267598abd6a026f229ef6b45/114x114.png"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://assets.guim.co.uk/images/favicons/873381bf11d58e20f551905d51575117/72x72.png"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="https://assets.guim.co.uk/images/favicons/6a2aa0ea5b4b6183e92d0eac49e2f58b/57x57.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/2015-06-24-manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials"><link rel="amphtml" href="https://amp.theguardian.com/money/2019/dec/10/starbucks-gift-card-refused-franchise-stores"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://assets.guim.co.uk/images/favicons/46bd2faa1ab438684a6d4528a655a8bd/32x32.ico"/><link rel="canonical" href="https://www.theguardian.com/money/2019/dec/10/starbucks-gift-card-refused-franchise-stores"/><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Guardian"/><meta name="application-name" content="The Guardian"/><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#052962"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#052962"><meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://assets.guim.co.uk/images/favicons/023dafadbf5ef53e0865e4baaaa32b3b/windows_tile_144_b.png"/><link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/113000071431138202574"/><meta name="author" content="Rebecca Smithers"/><meta name="thumbnail" content="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/843b4d2dc4f73319eba6210d4d68509119b702c2/0_0_4096_2458/master/4096.jpg?width=620&amp;quality=85&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;s=adbfbb41f5b50749f72609024e473493"/><meta name="keywords" content="Consumer rights,Money,Starbucks,Retail industry"/><meta name="news_keywords" content="Consumer rights,Money,Starbucks,Reta
```

this is the webView codes in the main activity that i get the string from the database by id number

```
     web_View = findViewById(R.id.webView);

     web_View.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

     if (CheckInternet.isNetwork(getApplicationContext())) {
        if(url2!=null) {
            Log.e("url2", url2);
            web_View.loadUrl(url2);
        }
       } else {

        int data = getUrl.getIntExtra("data",0);


       String a = FavNewsDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).noteDao().loadSingle(data);
            Log.e("data2",a);
        String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(a.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);

    web_View.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");

    }
```

how I can open it with the images and **THANKS**

Comment: I see no images in the html. Do you? After half an hour scrolling ? What do you expect us to do?

Comment: this is the main url 
 https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/dec/10/russia-ukraine-tentative-progress-at-first-talks-for-three-years
and I saw this way i can get the content of a web

Comment: For the images probably relative paths will be used in the src attibute of the img tag. You are loading only a html page and there is no reference to the original website then i think. You could add a base url. But then you use this only when offline (which you forgot to mention).

Comment: @blackapps yes sorry for not mentioning this is for offline use

Comment: i tired with loadDataWithBaseURL it gives me the base64 code and not opening the webpage

Comment: You are again not telling what you are doing. If you are offline it makes no sense to use a base url. I said that before.

Comment: I'm downloading the webcontent to use offline later

Comment: Yes. I even suggested you were doing that. What has it to do with loadDataWithBaseURL ? You dont need that for downloading.

Comment: okay so what about getting the image what i need to do
it opens only the texts but not the images

Comment: Of course you see no images. Html pages do not contain images. They are only text. They contain img tags with src attributes whith relative or full paths to images which are on the internet too. If your html page (loaded from database) used full paths (http(s) url) for the images and you were online the WebView would automatically download them and you would see them.

Comment: okay is there any way to save all the images offline ?

Comment: Yes. Of course. And you can imagine what has to be done too. And if you can download a html page then you can download images too. (well code should be adpted for not text files).

Comment: I cant Find any example :)

Comment: For which step do you need an example? There are many steps. Please first tell which steps you all have to do. Come to the point please.

Comment: I just want offline webcontent with pictures so i want something like the string posted include the images may my all code is wrong (just need help about it) i'm already getting the offline web but without images

Comment: You told nothing new. We know already what you want. Now you first should realise what has to be done. Then tell us the steps.

Comment: I dont know what to do that's why i'm asking for an advise or someone help me with a simple code

Comment: if I open the url once then save the webpage the images is normal but if I save the webpage without opening it once it doesn't show it

Comment: I dont know what you mean with that opening and not opening once and further. And further i gave you already advice. I told you why you dont see the images. So then you know what to do now. The steps you should take now.

Comment: if I'm on the net and pressed the item its shows everything normally because I have internet . Now I have a button that the user can press when they are online to download the webpage on every row for offline use now we have 2 options FIRST: if the user opens the link once online and save it later everything works perfectly SECOND : if the user save the webpage without opening it once and want to use it offline later it will show him the page without loading the images

Comment: So until now you only downloaded the html page. And the images stayed on the internet. Now if you also want to see the images when you are offline. Then it is clear what you have to do before you go offline. Or not? Imagine!

Comment: And i have no idea what you mean with FIRST and SECOND and 'items' and 'every row' and so on and what is that 'link' ?

Comment: its recyclerView that contains webUrl -_-